# How to use ostream_iterator<> to output result to a newfile?

Tags: c++

I am a fresh about C++, I have met an issue, I want to use the following codes (from Cplusplus ) but to output my result to a new file or use a vector to keep it(i prefer to use a vector), what should I do? 
Thanks!

```
// ostream_iterator example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::ostream_iterator
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i*10);

  std::ostream_iterator<int> out_it (std::cout,", ");
  std::copy ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), out_it );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `std::ofstream` in place of `std::cout`.

Here's your code modified to write the output to a file.

```
// ostream_iterator example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::ostream_iterator
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy
#include <fstream>      // std::ofstream

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i*10);

  std::ofstream of("myoutput.txt");

  std::ostream_iterator<int> out_it (of,", ");
  std::copy ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), out_it );
  return 0;
}
```

To copy the output to a `vector`, use a `back_inserter`.

```
std::vector<int> foo;
std::copy (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), std::back_inserter(foo));
```

You can also make direct copy:

```
std::vector<int> foo = myvector;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!   how about to keep the output in a vector?